# Data-service resolving object, but server catching is as a rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

My server has a route,

```
app.get(("/employees/:id"), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.paramas.id); //prints correctly
    data.getEmployeeByNum(req.params.id).then((data) => {
        res.json(data);
    }).catch(function(reason) {
        console.log("An error was encountered: " + reason);
    });
});
```

And `getEmployeeByNum()` is defined as,

```
module.exports.getEmployeeByNum = function(num) {
    return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
        var temp = [];
        let j = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            if (employees[i].employeeNum == num) {
                temp[j] = employees[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        console.log("LENGTH IS: " + temp.length); //LENGTH IS: 1 (which is exactly what I need)
        if (temp.length == 0) {
            console.log("we bad");
            reject("No results");
        } else {
            console.log("we good"); //prints this line
            resolve(temp);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can note, `console.log("we good");` gets called as it should, and my function resolves the array of one employee. But my call to this function catches it as an error, and prints `An error was encountered: [object Object]`. Any thoughts? Im breaking my head over this.

Answer (score 0):

Im an idiot.

```
module.exports.getEmployeeByNum = function(num) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

not

```
module.exports.getEmployeeByNum = function(num) {
return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
```